# Notepad++ regex to find filename in html code

Tags: regex, notepad++, filenames

I need to search for file names in html code.

Text to search

```txt
D: \ Fitos \ excel \ ([1-9] [0-9] *) (. Xlsx “target =” _ top "> Old pdf)
```

Replace with

```txt
D: \ Fitos \ excel2 \ $ 2 (.xlsx “target =” _ top "> Old Pdf)
```

with this regex search I find Excel files like 13037.xlsx

What if I wanted to search the text ES-00106.pdf with a regular expression?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex should be:

```
D:\\Fitos\\excel\\([1-9][0-9]*)\.xlsx "target"="_top"> Old pdf
```

for the replacement value I think you need $1 as you are using the first grouped section (the whole regex match being $0), so:

```
D:\Fitos\excel2\$1.xlsx "target"="_top"> Old pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
What if I wanted to search the text ES-00106.pdf with a regular expression?

Comment: No one would be so kind to help me? I've been googling and trying with no success.

Comment: `D:\\Fitos\\excel\\([1-9][0-9]*)\.xlsx" target="_top">Pdf antiguo` works well but i would like to find ES-00106.pdf with a regular expression